# After Updating Name of The Entity ,Updated Entity Comes Last In The Json

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, crud

Inside restController package

```
@PutMapping("update/{id}")
public void update(@RequestBody UpdateLanguagesRequest updateLanguages,int id) {
    this.languagesService.update(updateLanguages, id);
}
```

Inside language manager

@Override

```
public void update(UpdateLanguagesRequest updateLanguageRequest,int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Languages language=this.languageRepository.findById(id).get();
    language.setName(updateLanguageRequest.getName());
    this.languageRepository.save(language);
    this.languageRepository.flush();
    //language=getLanguageById; 
}
```

After updatind spesific element(e.g id=2) in database it becomes
[image]
id 3 comes before than id 2 how can i fix this?(I did not add the other apis like get add that is because they are working without error)

Comment: You must annotate 'id' parameter with @PathVariable in 'update' method in RestController class.

Comment: @artild it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken a quick look at your repository, I'll show the two required modifications. You can add a `findAllOrderByIdAsc` method to your repository:

```
public interface LanguagesRepository extends JpaRepository<Languages,Integer> {
 List<Languages> findAllByOrderByIdAsc();               
}
```

and use it in your service layer instead like this:

```
@Override
    public List<GetAllLanguagesResponses> getAllResponse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Languages> languages=this.languageRepository.findAllByOrderByIdAsc();
        //this.languageRepository.flush();
        List<GetAllLanguagesResponses>languageResponse=new ArrayList<>();
        for(Languages language:languages) {
            GetAllLanguagesResponses responseItem=new GetAllLanguagesResponses();
            responseItem.setId(language.getId());
            responseItem.setName(language.getName());
            languageResponse.add(responseItem);
        }   
        return languageResponse;    
        
    }
```

Comment: if jparepository has this method in it by default what is the meaning of writing  that inside of Languages repository again,if not then should i also implement it

Comment: @samaritan it doesn't already have it, spring data JPA derives the query from the name of the method in your repository. You don't need to implement it yourself, but you have to add it to the interface so it can be derived for you.

Comment: @samaritan take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries for an introduction.

Comment: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.ProgrammingLanguages.dataAccess.concretes.LanguagesRepository.findAllOrderByIdAsc(); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.ProgrammingLanguages.dataAccess.concretes.LanguagesRepository.findAllOrderByIdAsc()! No property 'asc' found for type 'int' Traversed path: Languages.id.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method

Comment: @samaritan possibly an error because you are using a primitive for id, you should use a wrapper instead. Change this in your entity: `private int id;` to `private Integer id;`. Also I made a typo in the repository method name so please update that, too.

Comment: I got your point but i want to use int as id ,could you suggest anything else?

Comment: @samaritan try it without changing that, only fix the typo, note the added `By` in `findAllByOrderByIdAsc`.

Comment: it was really helpful thanks,another short question i need findById in my business.Jpa has  that but it returns Optional .Im using that inside my business after adding findById(id).get .Would it make sense to adding that method also interface?

Comment: @samaritan It's better to use the method that returns Optional<T> since it enables more graceful error handling. However, if you really want to you can add `Languages findById` to your repository, it should be null if no value was found.